# Add html to drupal 6 page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to add html to the bottom of all the pages of a drupal 6 site.

I tried following [Adding HTML to Drupal closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377855/adding-html-to-drupal-closure) but I'm not familiar enough with drupal to follow it.

The code is a google remarketing code, so I can't use drupal_add_js because the code I have already has script tags and , and the drupal_add_js wraps everything in  tags.

hook_footer seems to be the best solution but I can't figure out how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use hook_footer().
You have to create a Drupal module. I think this link might help you: https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7

Basically you have to create a module an implementes hook_footer(). In here you can add your custom html.

But there are another ways to do it. For example you can edit your theme. Find the page.tpl.php file in your theme and add, in the footer, the content. It's appears in all pages.

Another option is to create a block with full html filter, and add your html.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't realize I needed to add a module in order to use hook_footer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting the html i needed in $vars["closure"]